# passing a querystring from one of the griditems bound columns

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I have a gridview, one of the item in the gridview is

```
<asp:GridBoundColumn DataField="Id"  UniqueName="Id" DataType="System.Int32"   Visible="false"></asp:GridBoundColumn>
```

and another item is

```
 <asp:ImageButton id="RadButton_RunQuery" ImageUrl="~/images/run_query_button.jpg" PostBackUrl="~/Viewer/ViewerSummary.aspx?QueryID=" runat="server" />
```

want to pass Id from the `asp:GridBoundColumn` as a querystring to the postbackurl of the `asp:imageButton`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Do you use jquery in your project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with this code

```
PostBackUrl='<%# "~/Viewer/ViewerSummary.aspx?QueryID=" + DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ID") %>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using an ImageButton then that means you are using an ItemTemplate. You can do something like this:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
<ItemTemplate>
  <asp:ImageButton id="RadButton_RunQuery" ImageUrl="~/images/run_query_button.jpg" 
   PostBackUrl='<%#string.Format("~/Viewer/ViewerSummary.aspx?QueryID={0}",Eval("Id")) %>' runat="server" />
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```